# How to unload objects from memory while reading realm data in batches

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

Following is code example (in swift) given by Realm team to read subset of entire result set:

```
// Loop through the first 5 Dog objects
// restricting the number of objects read from disk
let dogs = try! Realm().objects(Dog.self)
for i in 0..<5 {
    let dog = dogs[i]
    // ...
}
```

Ref: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/ (Limiting Results)

Now I understand objects are loaded as we read them from realm, I am little confused as how realm unloads them from memory as we keep progressing. For example, if my query returns 100 objects as a result set and I read first 10 objects, then on user interaction I read next 10 and so on. Now what will happen to previously read objects in memory. How can I control memory usage in such cases as I may want to unload previous subset when I read a newer one.

My guess is I may need invalidate old realm and make a new connection to fetch result set again and read again from a new offset. Invalidating may unload everything read previously. Please suggest.

Thank you!

Comment: Slightly off topic but in that code, each iteration through the loop creates a dog object with `let dog =` but then the next iteration through the loop releases that object and creates a new one. When the loop terminates, there will be no dog object as it's now out of scope. I mention that as the provided code is probably not the best example of dealing with memory constraints. Can you provide an example for your use case? In other words, *if my query returns 100 objects* means you have a reference to those objects, what you do with those results is what we need to know.

Comment: @Jay I did some more investigation into this and it looks like Realm always reads object properties from databases on get access calls. So even if I read them and then invalidate realm, on accessing read objects again raises exception. So I believe I don't need to worry about unloading them from memory. By the way, how is this an off topic? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry. *My comment* was slightly off topic. You asked about unloading from memory and I addressed the code in the question instead of answering your question. I would encourage you to update your question with code for your use case because there are situations where you do need to be memory conscience. For example: a results object of 100 dogs and then this `let x = Array(results). Those 100 lazily loaded dog objects are now in memory as a non-lazily loaded array. Or a tableView datasource that's an array copied from realm results - that array is now in memory.

Comment: Yes, I understand any other objects (UI Elements) may hold a strong references to realm object properties and thus they will continue to live in memory until strong references are released. I gave a generic example to understand how people use various access patterns in different ways from purely an academic perspective. Anyways, I appreciate your time. Thanks for your kind help. Cheers!